# Spring Roo addon creation exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I am trying to create a simple addon using the script provided with the roo 1.1.0M3 zip but

I am getting this error

Could not locate '/org/springframework/roo/addon/creator/simple\roo-addon-simple-template.xml'

in classloader

Script execution aborted

Can anybody please help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified whether the mentionned file is in your classpath (in a jar included in the workspace classpath where you are developing your extension)?

If not, you'll probably solve the problem adding the right jar to your classpath.